# Interleave SSL_read and SSL_read from a single thread

Tags: openssl, tls1.2, nonblocking

I have a TCP client and sever communicating over OpenSSL, using non-blocking sockets. All socket reads and writes are always executed from a single thread. The connection is open till the client is running and the communication doesn’t follow a request-reply model.

The client continuously sends messages to the server, which logs the messages into the database. The client can occasionally send the request for data and will read them from the socket:

## Client

```
SSL_write...                                                        
SSL_write 
SSL_write
```

...
Write a request to get data from the DB 
(Waiting for data in SSL_read ...)

```
SSL_read
```

...Received data, resume writing

```
SSL_write
SSL_write
SSL_write
```

## Server

The server reads in a loop till data are available
When the request for data from the DB is received, second thread prepares the data while the read loop in the main thread continues. Because the client is waiting for data, the SSL_read on the server will fail with SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ.

Handling the error SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
The server tries if the socket is readable, and if it is not, the reading is finished, sends data to the client if available in a buffer, and the main loop goes to the Select to listen for incoming messages.

The client successfully receives the data and tries to write to the server again. But from this point the server doesn’t register them on the socket, and the data are not written into the database.

## Question:

1/ Is this model, when client is sending SSL_write occasionally interrupted with SSL_read appropriate for OpenSSL?

2/Would it be proper for the server to send the response back to the client (SSL_write) in the middle of the SSL_read loop?

3/ What is the proper approach?

Thanks for any ideas.

## Edit1:

Basically what is happening, it is that after the server successfully sends data back to a client, the Select in the server doesn't signal any file descriptors ready. Note, that the client sends further data after receiving data from the server. Data are sent from the client without error, however the server Select doesn't respond to them.

## EDIT2:

I noticed that my Ubuntu 18.04 updated the OpenSSL from 1.1.0g to 1.1.1, and the mentioned issue started after this upgrade only.

Comment: You may be getting burned by thinking that the SSL connection has two states like a TCP connection does. An SSL connection has only one state. So, for example, if an `SSL_read` returned a `WANT_READ` indication but you then performed an `SSL_write`, the `WANT_READ` indication is now obsolete and you should *not* call `select` before calling `SSL_read`. There isn't still a "read state" that's still "need to read from the socket". The `SSL_write` changed the connection's one and only state. So it's not safe to block in `select`!

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem without interleaving the SSL_read and SSL_write : the client sends write and the 2nd write happens only after a while (aka sporadic logging).
The server receives data from the 1st client write, and enters the read loop. Because the client is not sending data, I am leaving this loop as no data are coming, expecting to catch any new data with main select signalling file descriptors ready.The connection has not been closed so read tries to read.
In this scenario I am not writing anything.

Comment: You should never call `select` to wait to attempt a call to `SSL_read` unless a call to `SSL_read` *just* told you to. Otherwise, call `SSL_read` if you want to read. Call `select` if `SSL_read` tells you to.

Comment: That's what I am doing when I get error_want_read during the read: call Select to see if the socket is readable. It is not. If I would keep trying, I would be in infinite loop.

Comment: So, to be clear, you *never* call `select` to wait to read unless a call to `SSL_read` *just* told you to?

Comment: I changed the code in the sense, that if I get want_read in read, and the socket is not readable, I try write if I have data. That seems to be working. The client gets data and keeps writing to the server after that. But that means that other clients can write only after the 1st client finishes. Only in that case the execution goes back to Select to check the new FDs ready. It seems to be not right.

Comment: You should only call `select` when *none* of your SSL connections can make forward progress any other way. Each of your connections has one and only one state, when *all* of them are in the state "cannot make forward progress until `select` says we can", then call `select`.

Comment: what is the correct way to find out if the socket is readable/writable on a connection? I did: when I get error during the read or write, i called only for this FD the select without blocking to see the result (non application data just passed through or not doing progress). If select would block during ssl-read, then I wrote data to a client...

Comment: You don't need to find out if the socket is readable/writable, you need to read or you need to write. If you need to read, call `SSL_read`. If you need to write, call `SSL_write`. If you get a WANT_READ indication and there is nothing else you need to do, then retry the operation later, using `select` to know when it's later if you wish.

Comment: Thanks. I think I have it OK now.